# am I mutating object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

am I mutating state object

```
state = {
  selectedHero: { id: "", name: "", saying: "" }
}
```

with this method

```
handleChange = e => {
  let selectedHero = this.state.selectedHero;
  selectedHero[e.target.name] = e.target.value;

  this.setState({ selectedHero });
};
```

should I write something like this?

```
handleChange = e => {
  let selectedHero = { ...this.state.selectedHero };
  selectedHero[e.target.name] = e.target.value;

  this.setState({ selectedHero });
};
```

Comment: console.log()..

Comment: As AnilRedshift says, yes the spread syntax example you give will work fine. For a neater approach you can also write it with a one liner like so: `this.setState({...this.state.selectedHero, name: e.target.value})`. This will overwrite the name value at the same time on the new object and avoid mutating.

Comment: @TPHughes - No, Anil's version fails to use the callback, which is necessary. Also, `name` != `[e.target.name]`. :-)

Comment: Ah yeah your absolutely right. I misread the key name as just `name`. I'm writing on my phone :-/. What do you mean, why is the callback necessary?

Comment: @TPHughes - See my answer below, and the link in it. :-)

Comment: @TPHughes - LOL, I hadn't put the link in! Have now. :-)

Comment: I had no idea! Thank you very informative. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no. You're not mutating `this.state`, but you are mutating an object `this.state` refers to. Which you shouldn't do in React.

> should I write something like this?

**Almost**; since that involves updating state based on state (the other properties of `selectedHero`), you [**must** use the callback version of `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). Since that means using properties from the synthetic event after `handleChange` returns, we'll need to grab them up-front:

```
handleChange = e => {
  const {name, value } = e.target;
  this.setState(prevState => {
    let selectedHero = { ...prevState.selectedHero };
    selectedHero[name] = value;
    return { selectedHero };
  })
};
```

If you don't use the callback version, things will appear to work much of the time, and fail when you have overlapping state updates to `selectedHero` (remember that state updates are asynchronous); one will stomp on the other.

---

If you like, you can also condense it by using a computed property name after the property spread:

```
handleChange = e => {
  const {name, value} = e.target;
  this.setState(prevState => ({selectedHero: {...prevState.selectedHero, [name]: value}}));
};
```

and even throw in some parameter destructuring:

```
handleChange = ({target: {name, value}}) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({selectedHero: {...prevState.selectedHero, [name]: value}}));
};
```

(Yes, the destructuring will happen before `handleChange` returns. It happens before your explicit code in `handleChange` runs at all.)

Comment: I'am getting warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `target` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist()

Comment: @d_oram - Oh wow, I didn't know about that. Nice clear error message though. We'll have to grab `name` and `value` locally and then use them. You probably know how to do that, but I'll update the answer anyway.

Comment: @d_oram - Done.

Comment: perfect, thank you. Can you please add closing parenthesis `})` after `return { selectedHero }`  in first example

Comment: @d_oram - Oops! The second and third were missing a `}` as well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are mutating the `selectedHero` object. You should do something like this:

```
handleChange = e => {
  let selectedHero = Object.assign({}, this.state.selectedHero);
  selectedHero[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
  this.setState({ selectedHero });
};
```

The `Object.assign` call will create a *new* object, so that your original selectedHero object is not modified

Edit: Your edited use of the [ES2018 spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) works too.

Comment: Since this involves setting state based on existing state (the other properties of `selectedHero` that you're copying), you *must* use the callback version of `setState`: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous Not doing so will appear to work much of the time, and fail when state updates are merged/batched.